# Algorithm to find out if a set contains two number with sum in the same set using a blackbox function

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I need help with the following question -
There is a set S of n integers.
Given a black box which returns three integers a,b,c in S such that a+b+c = 0 if they exist.
One needs to devise an algorithm that makes only one call to the black box to find out if S contains
three integers such that a+b=c

The question also had a hint -
Construct a set S' such that there exists  a',b',c' in S' such that a'+b'+c'=0 if and only if
there exists a,b,c in S such that a+b=c

Thanks

Comment: Try following the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is essentially answered on the Wikipedia page on the 3SUM problem, specifically the part on [3 different arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM#3_different_arrays).

Comment: But is the 3 different array solving problem using the black box call...? The title of the question is bit misleading as it actually asks you to solve the problem using the blackbox for which I think one has to construct the set

Comment: "Given a solver for 3SUM×1, the 3SUM×3 problem can be solved in the following way: ... Use the 3SUM×1 oracle"